# use if condition in query when the value is null

Tags: php, laravel

In SQL query i want to add if statement. if latitude and longitude null in database then query will run and fill the value in database

```
$users = DB::table('users',IF ($user->lat && $user->lng == Null))->get();

foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $response = Geocode::make()->address($user->zipcode);

    if ($response) {
        $lat =   $response->latitude();
        $lng =  $response->longitude();
        $city =   $response->formattedAddress();
        echo  $response->locationType();

        DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', $user->id)
            ->update(['lat' => $lat,'lng' => $lng,'city' => $city]);

    }
}
```

Comment: @MohamedSabil83        Same code but problem is diffrent." $response->formattedAddress();" this method get me full address but i want city and state in seperately. could you help me sir?

Comment: You can read the **Geocode** doc to know which function retrieves the city and which for the state

Comment: Not get Any idea

Comment: give me the link of **geocode** package. also, give me an example of `$response->formattedAddress()` output.

Comment: https://www.packalyst.com/packages/package/jcf/geocode                           previous example is same.

Comment: can you dump `$response->raw()->address_components`?

Comment: yes sir it get error. following is error " Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: see code.->   $city= $response->raw()->address_components[2]['long_name'];
                    $state= $response->raw()->address_components[3]['long_name'];

Comment: then `dd($response)` and paste output in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and give me the link to view

Comment: done sir. check sir on pastebin   https://pastebin.com/RswLPGnj

Comment: is it true, according to your lat and lang, the city is **Akola** and state is **Maharashtra**?

Comment: yes sir. city akola and state maharastra

Comment: error =>  " Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 ty so much for help. i solved my problem.

Comment: You're welcome and sorry I'm just busy. For other persons who may face/need the same details, I modified my answer to show how to get the city, state, and country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$users = User::whereNull('lat')->whereNull('lng')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $response = Geocode::make()->address($user->zipcode);

    if ($response) {
        $lat = $response->latitude();
        $lng = $response->longitude();
        $city = $response->formattedAddress();
        echo  $response->locationType();

        $user->update(['lat' => $lat,'lng' => $lng,'city' => $city]);
    }
}
```

More specific details:

```
$city = $response->raw()->address_components[1]['long_name'];
$state = $response->raw()->address_components[2]['long_name'];
$country = $response->raw()->address_components[3]['long_name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DB::table('users')->where([
    ['users.lat', '=', NULL],
    ['users.lng', '=', NULL])->get();
```